# PostgreSQL Replication working without error but no data synced

Tags: postgresql

I implemented PostgreSQl Logical Replication using pgAdmin GUI
i using Postgres SQL version 14

steps that I followed

1 - change on file `postgresql.conf` (on master server)

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on
wal_level = logical         # minimal, replica, or logical
```

2 - Create publication for Specific tables using pgAdmin GUI (On master server)

3 - Create Subscriber on Standby Server using PgAdmin GUI

[image]
[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

Table schema that I made update on:

```
   -- Table: public.Account

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public."Account";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Account"
(
    "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    "RegistrationDate" timestamp with time zone,
    "CreatedBy" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CreatedDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "ModifiedBy" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ModifiedDate" timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Account" PRIMARY KEY ("Id");
```

no any error message returned

But when I try to make update statement, the stand-by server is not affected with these changes i can not to know why

Comment: this should be asked in DBA

Comment: Did you create those tables on the standby? Did you look into the log file?

Comment: yes database master and slave have identical schama

Comment: Replication errors would get reported to the log file, not to pgAdmin4.